# Laravel - Multi domain using single login server?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I'm setting up around 4 `Laravel 5.3` based apps at the moment, they are all part of one "ecosystem".

I plan to use a central `Laravel` app that will handle any user signup, user login and also hold all user details. These details will be used across the 4 separate Laravel web apps. I may also use these user details inside mobile apps in the future so I assume i'll need some sort of JWT based system to control this.

I've thought about using `Laravel Passport` to achieve this but I don't think this will work for this scenario. In all honesty, the documentation is not clear to me whether this is the sort of system it is designed for or if I need to use a different oAuth2 system. My understanding is it is for API authentication only, or am I wrong?

All my other Laravel apps will be on different servers so I can't share the database unfortunately. I need to implement a cross domain solution it seems.

Thanks in advance for any info on this, just to clarify that I am *not* asking you to code the script for me, simply to help point me in the right direction on how to do this properly - can't really show code on something I don't know!

I believe I have explained *everything* that I am trying to achieve here, and I have already done research but nothing seems to be clicking in my brain.

Comment: Why the downvote? I've done research, presented my findings and asking for help... Could at least leave a reason, *sigh*

Comment: @Epodax I'm not sure how it's so broad? Passport allows for OAUTH2 server to be set up, which sounds like the right thing to do, however I don't believe it suits this project as my users will use a web app primarily, and then mobile apps later on down the line.

So my question is basically asking if there is a good way to utilise a central laravel app that contains all the users (the main site) and have the other servers speak to that to get the user data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it depends on your business logic. Below is what i'm thinking:

1. If what you mean `Multi Domains` is the sub domains (as you mentioned `login.site.com`), i think the simplest way is to use `site.com` wide cookie with redis/memcached as the session storage solution.
2. If they do have different domain names, and beyond the central site, user when visit site A also want site B feature (or content, those sites are closely connected), i thought the JWT solution is the better choice.
3. Any other cases, choose OAuth

Well, maybe others have better ideas.

Comment: That's a good answer and makes sense. It's likely that I will have one central site like this `maincompany.com` where user data, user sign up and user register will be handed, and then the multi apps that are part of this umbrella are separate servers/domains like `app1.com`, `app2.com` and `app3.com` all hosted on different Laravel Forge deployed servers. Looks like I'll probably go with option 2, at least until i've explored `Passport`'s complete capabilities :)